# Find pairs of cells that meet a condition then do something excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that searches for bold characters in a specific column. In my case column C. What I want it to do is find pairs of cells that contain bold characters then search in column I to see if something exists between them. I know how to handle from there on out. I am just stuck on how to find pairs of cells that meet the condition.

Here is the function:

```
Function FindBoldCharacters(ByVal aCell As Range) As Boolean
    FindBoldCharacters = IsNull(aCell.Font.Bold)
    If Not FindBoldCharacters Then FindBoldCharacters = aCell.Font.Bold
End Function
```

Here is how the function is called in the code

```
    For Each i In Range("C11:C300")
            If FindBoldCharacters(i) = True Then
                'do some stuff here'
                Set s = i
                s.Interior.ColorIndex = 8 '''for testing purposes''' 


            Else

            End If
    Next i
```

I know that the way it is currently called it searches for all of the cells that meet the condition. I just don't know how to write it to stop and `do something` when it meets the condition twice. Also, for this to work properly it must retain the second of the two met conditions or else there will be a gap between each pair.

I would like a push in the right direction. I don't necessarily want an entire section of code written for me, but if that's the case please explain how it works. I want to learn about vba, not just implement it and forget it.

**UPDATE**

Essentially this is what I want to happen

[image: Results example]

Comment: Create a variable to serve as a flag and set it to 0 at first. Add 1 when first bold found. Then add 1 again when second bold found. Include a `if variable =2 then` within your for loop to trigger whatever it is you want to do. Not sure what you mean by retain second of condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you were trying to do

```
Option Explicit

Sub findBoldCells()
    Dim cel As Range, fnd1 As Long, fnd2 As Long, i As Long, cl As Long

    cl = RGB(222, 255, 255)

    For Each cel In Range("C11:C300")

        If cel.Font.Bold = True Then
            If fnd1 = 0 Then fnd1 = cel.Row Else fnd2 = cel.Row
        End If

        If fnd1 > 0 And fnd2 > 0 Then   'we found 1st and 2nd cell with bold text

            Range(Range("C" & fnd1), Range("C" & fnd2)).Interior.Color = cl

            If fnd2 > fnd1 Then
                Range("C" & fnd1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                Range("C" & fnd2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If

            For i = fnd1 To fnd2
                With Range("I" & i)
                    .Interior.Color = vbCyan 'check values in col I...
                    .Value2 = i
                End With
            Next

            fnd1 = 0: fnd2 = 0    'prepare for next iteration

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Kind of. Except between the bold areas if any numbers are present they will be the same, and the cell in column C that is bold will not contain a number in column I. I updated my question to show a better explanation of what I mean.

Comment: The answer shows you how to find pairs of cells that meet a condition (first bold cell to the next bold cell); it doesn't do anything else, except use an example of how you can act on values in column I. (you'll need to create your own logic for the "check values in col I...") Let me know if you need details about how it determines if it meets the condition twice